# datepicker for dynamically created textbox not working on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery Datepicker function :

```
function myFunction(ID) {
    var id = ID;
    $( "#datepicker23" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0
    });

    $( "#datepicker22" ).datepicker({
      minDate: 0
    });

    $( "#datepicker14" ).datepicker({
      minDate: 0
    });

}
```

My input tag for selecting the date picker, 3 input boxes are created dynamically, with id's datepicker23, datepicker22, datepicker14,

```
<input type="text" onclick="myFunction('+standNo+')" id="datepicker'+standNo+'" required/>
```

Calendar shows only on the second click on the input box

Comment: Why not just use the jQuery click function?

Comment: Why would it? Datepicker needs to listen to the event to open. But event has already occurred when you initialize it. Initialize the datepicker when you insert the element

Comment: Why you don't need id variable?

Comment: `id="datepicker'+standNo+'"` - What on earth even is that?  It's not clear what the actual problem is here that you're trying to describe.  Can you provide a working example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: i think the variable `standNo` is ending its scope due to `onclick myFunction` -  did you try to alerting the ID within the function?